# why there are different ways to specify a directory in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I notice that in following `.gitignore` file, `logs` folder is specified as `logs` while `.idea` and `out` are specified as `/.idea` and `/out`? Why? When should I use `/` in front of a directory or file name?

```
logs
project/project
project/target
target
tmp
.history
dist
/.idea
/*.iml
/out
/.idea_modules
/.classpath
/.project
/RUNNING_PID
/.settings
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). The answer to your question is available (with examples) on the [PATTERN FORMAT](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)  section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/folder` only match the folder named `folder` at the root of your git repo.

For instance, consider the following folders:

```
.
├── logs
│   └── logs1
├── subdir
│   ├── logs
│   │   └── logs3
│   ├── logs2
│   └── temp
│       └── temp2
└── temp
    └── temp1

5 directories, 5 files
```

and the following `.gitignore`:

```
logs
/temp
```

both `./logs` and `./subdir/logs` are ignored while only `./temp` is ignored (and not `./subdir/temp`)